# Angular 8 after deploying icons not loading

Tags: angular, angular8

Recently we migrated our project from 7 to Angular 8 version. On local everything works fine but on prod icons and images dont load. It gives 404 not found. Although other items are loading successfully.
Is there any update for loading the icons

Comment: did you check if your icons and images are in the dist folder after build?

Comment: In index.html try changing `<base href="/">` to `<base href="./">`

Comment: Yes they are there in dist folder

Comment: Nothing works after  <base href="/"> to <base href="./"> @SudiptoMukherjee

Comment: can you share your image tag how you are calling

Comment: For ex  href="./assets/images/favicon.png" favicon icon also fails